# SQL limit for XML type

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, truncate

I am actually working on a large database and I am querying the following data;

**My Query:**

```
SELECT ldd.LDistCD, ldd.LDistDescPay
FROM   LDetail ldd
INNER JOIN LDist ld
ON         ldd.ID = ld.ID 
AND        ld.ID = '019458' 
AND        ld.LDistType = 'F'
```

**Result:** 
[image: 87]

What I am doing next, is to loop across the results (27873) in my VB codes to concatenate the data in the following format;

```
LDistCD + '|' + LDistDescPay
```

Normally that would be a very time consuming time looping through all these rows. Hence to optimise the work, I am using the following query which should already concatenate the data for me;

```
SELECT stuff((SELECT ',' + ldd.LddLabourDistCD + '|' + ldd.LddLabourDistDescPay
              FROM   LDetail ldd
              INNER JOIN LDist ld
              ON ldd.ID = ld.ID
              AND ld.ID = 019425 AND ld.LDistType = 'F'
       FOR XML
PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Everything is working fine except for the result, whereby some data is being truncated!! Running the last query on MS SQL Server returns the concatenate result but it is not complete. I get the impression there's a limit to the result which is being exceeded.

Can anyone help on the issue please? 
Difficult for me to upload the db or the result but just to tell you that the 27873 rows, when concatenated in one string, is not fitting in the result.

Comment: is the result concatenated when it comes back into the VB code or just what yo are seeing in SSMS?  What is the length of the data that comes back?  There are two limits in SSMS that you can see by going to the query options: 2 MB for XML, 65535 for non-XML. Those are the defaults and you can increase the XML limit but not the non-XML limit. But those limits don't affect what gets sent back to the client, just what you see in SSMS.

Comment: in both MSSQL when dry-run the query and on VB, I am getting the same result. Concatenating the 2 columns for the 27800+ rows, do output a large string!

Comment: so what is the length of the string that comes back into the VB code?

Comment: In fact, the second query returns only one row of concatenated data -> 65535 bytes

Comment: What second query? You only show one query. And 65535 is the limit in SSMS. Is that the exact length of the value coming back into the VB code? It shouldn't be.

Comment: I mean the query with `stuff..`, and yeah I get exactly 65535 bytes as result. meaning the rest is being truncated because of limit-overflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60181/discussion-between-srutzky-and-nadeem-mk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truncation you are seeing is specific to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). If you go to the **Query** menu and select **Query Options...**, then go to **Results** and then to **Grid**, you should see on the right side a section for "Maximum Characters Retrieved". The "Non XML data" has a max of 65,535 (which should also be the default) and the "XML data" is a drop-down with options:

- 1 MB
- 2 MB (default)
- 5 MB
- Unlimited

Since the `XML` datatype can bring back more than 65,535 characters, you can convert your output to XML (this is only needed when using SSMS; client libraries should pull back the full string):

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML,
        stuff((SELECT ',' + ldd.LddLabourDistCD + '|' + ldd.LddLabourDistDescPay 
        FROM LDetail ldd 
        INNER JOIN LDist ld 
        ON ldd.ID = ld.ID 
        AND ld.ID = 019425
        AND ld.LDistType = 'F' 
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
       )
```